# Leer multiples lineas en un fichero en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola amigos estoy creando un fichero con funciones en python y necesito hacer una funcion que pueda sumarme los numeros enteros que contienen las lineas que estan dentro del fichero,  he conseguido hacer que solo me lea la primera linea con la funcion `fichero.readline()` pero al querer cambiarlo a `readlines()` me lanza error

```py
def crear_archivo(nombre):
    fichero = open(nombre,"w")
    fichero.close()

def escribir_fichero(nombre):
    fichero=open(nombre,"w")
    linea1= "1 a 2 b \n"
    fichero.write(linea1)
    linea2 = "3 c 4 d \n"
    fichero.write(linea2)
    fichero.close()

def muestra_pantalla(nombre):
    fichero=open(nombre, "r")
    linea = 0
    for i in fichero:
        print("Linea",str(linea),": ",str(i))
        linea = linea + 1
    fichero.close()

def suma_ficheros(nombre): #Esta seria la funcion
    fichero=open(nombre,"r")
    suma=0 #Creo la variable para guardar las sumas
    linea= fichero.readline() #SOlo puedo leer la primera linea
    lista = linea.split()`
    for x in lista:
        try:
            if isinstance(int(x), (int)):
                suma = suma + int(x)
        except Exception:
            print(x ,"Es una letra")
    print("La suma de los numeros es ", suma)
```

La salida hasta ahora es esta:

```
Linea 0 :  1 a 2 b 

Linea 1 :  3 c 4 d 

a Es una letra
b Es una letra
La suma de los numeros es  3
```

Comment: Creo que el código está mal formateado. ¿No debería estar el último `for` dentro de la función `suma_ficheros()`?

Comment: `readline()` lee una sola línea y devuelve una cadena. En cambio `readlines()` lee todas las líneas y devuelve **una lista**, cuyos elementos son cada una de las líneas. Cuando después intentas aplicar `.split()`, falla, pues lo estás aplicando a una lista. Puede resultarte mucho más sencillo usar `.read()` que devuelve el fichero completo como una sola cadena (con `\n` para los retornos de carro que separan las líneas). Aplicar `.split()` sobre esa cadena te lo dividirá en números, usando espacios o retornos de carro como separadores, por lo que creo que funcionará sin más.

Comment: Nota al pie: no uses readlines. Carga todo el archivo en memoria antes de procesarlo, lo que puede causar líos con archivos lo suficientemente grandes.

Comment: si tabule mal a la hora de copiar el for en la funcion pero esta dentro @abulafia

Comment: no se si te entendi muy bien al usar read() para leerme todo el fichero luego separo la linea con un .split(), pero claro me leera las dos lineas al mismo tiempo y me imprimira la suma en total de las dos lineas yo quiero la suma de cada linea no se si me dejo entender @abulafia

Comment: @Rebc3sp Ah, pensé que querías la suma total. Si vas a hacerlo línea por línea, no veo mucho sentido en usar `readlines()` entonces, especialmente si el fichero es muy grande, pues puede no entrar en memoria completo. Aún así, como referencia de cómo sería: `lineas = fichero.readlines()` y después `for linea in lineas:` y ya a cada línea le haces el procesamiento (`.split()` o lo que sea). Otra alternativa mejor: `for linea in fichero:` pues esto no intenta cargar todas las líneas de una vez en memoria, sino que lee una línea en cada iteración.

Comment: mmm sabes que salta a la segunda linea sin pasar por la primera no se que estoy haciendo mal te dejo el codigo , si podrias mostrarme algun ejemplo , crees que un bucle anidado puedo hacerlo?@abulafia

Comment: `lineas = fichero.readline()
    lista = lineas.split()
    for lista in fichero:
        try:
            if isinstance(int(lista), (int)):
                suma = suma + int(lista)
        except Exception:
            print(lista ,"Es una letra")
    
    print("La suma de los numeros es ",suma)`

Comment: Para aclarar, lo último que comentas  pasa porque cuando llamas a `readline` el cursor en el fichero se mueve al final de la primera linea, por lo que el `for` siguiente continua iterando desde esa posición (internamente el iterador encargado de ir retornando las líneas en el `for` usa también la implementación de `readline` exactamente igual que `readlines` para construir la lista).

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si de lo que se trata es de que se muestre, para cada línea del fichero, la suma de los números que hay en esa línea, la función podría quedar así:

```
def suma_fichero(nombre): 
    suma=0 #Creo la variable para guardar las sumas

    # Uso un contexto para abrir el fichero, así no se nos olvidará cerrarlo
    # (el contexto lo cerrará al salir del mismo)
    with open(nombre,"r") as fichero:
        for linea in fichero:
            # Cada línea se trocea y se procesa
            for x in linea.split():
                try:
                    # Simplifico. Si no es un entero, el siguiente int(x) 
                    # producirá excepción
                    suma = suma + int(x)
                except Exception:
                    print(x, "es una letra")
    print("La suma de los numeros es ", suma)
```